# could not capture down arrow in combobox in wpf

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a combobox on a window in wpf and i am trying to capture the down arrow key of this combobox but i am not able to do so. The following is the only code i have for the combobox.

```
<ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"
              PreviewKeyDown="comboBox1_PreviewKeyDown" KeyDown="comboBox1_KeyDown" IsEditable="True"/>
```

C#

```
private void comboBox1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Down)
            MessageBox.Show("hi");
    }

    private void comboBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Down)
            MessageBox.Show("hi");
    }
```

The event is not even hit when i press down arrow key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try handling PreviewKeyUp (or KeyUp) instead.  If that does not work, then there must be more to your window or code (are you handling other instances of these events)?

Comment: Hi Wonko the PreviewKeyUp event worked. But can you please explain y PreviewKeyDown event did not get fired for down arrow key???

Comment: I am not positive on this, but I believe it has to do with the fact that PreviewKeyDown is a tunneling event.  By making the ComboBox editable, I believe that the TextBox that becomes part of the ControlTemplate for the ComboBox is swallowing up that event.

Comment: Doesn't the fact that it's a tunneling event mean samar's PreviewKeyDown event handler should fire before the TextBox has a chance to handle it?

Answer (score 2):

This code is helpful for me.

```
<StackPanel PreviewKeyDown="StackPanel_PreviewKeyDown">
    <ComboBox>
        <ComboBoxItem>item1</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>item2</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>item3</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
</StackPanel>
```

CodeBehind

```
private void StackPanel_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Down)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Simple and robust solution. I confirm that it is a well-functioning solution and a suitable answer.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Combo box class by inheriting from the base ComboBox. Below code explains how to. You may come across such problems when you add combo box to another control like Data grid cell. Hope this helps!

http://csharpquestsolution.blogspot.com/2013/11/arrow-key-events-not-getting-fired-on.html

```
public class MyComboBox : ComboBox
{
    protected override bool ProcessKeyMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        KeyEventArgs keyArgs = new KeyEventArgs((Keys)m.WParam);
        switch(keyArgs.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.Up :
                //Implement your code here.
                return true;
            case Keys.Down :
                //Implement your code here.
                return true;
        }
        return base.ProcessKeyMessage(ref m);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is WinForms, not WPF.

Comment: @OlaBerntsson Yes its for WinForms and this solution was for a particular scenario, It might not be required with latest versions. Thought it might help with WPF as well or some one.